# json encoding from array issue

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json

Hi I'm trying to json_code an associative array where the end result should look like this json array below

```
   var json =[{  "adjacencies": [
      {
        "nodeTo": "graphnode9",
        "nodeFrom": "graphnode5",
        "data": {}
      }
    ],
    "data": {
      "$color": "#C74243",
      "$type": "triangle"
    },
    "id": "graphnode5",
    "name": "graphnode5"
  }];
```

Here is my attempt at getting an associative array into json_encode but it doesnt seem to work, is there any errors you might see? thank you so much

```
   function getjson(){  
   $db = adodbConnect();
   $query = "SELECT nodes.*, relationships.* FROM nodes inner JOIN relationships ON nodes.id = relationships.id";
  $result = $db -> Execute($query);

  while($row=$result->FetchRow())
   {
  $id= (float)$row['id'];
  $name = $row['name'];
  $color1 = $row['color'];
  $type1 = $row['type'];
  $to= (float)$row['to'];

  $array = array(
  "adjacencies:" => array(
  "nodeTo" => "$to",
  "nodeFrom" => "$id",
  "data" => array() ),
  "data" => array(
   "$"."color" => $color1,
   "$"."type" => $type1 ),
  "id".":" => $id,
  "name".":" => $name);

}
print"$array";
json_encode($array);
}
```

Comment: And what are you getting as a result?

Comment: You don't do anything with `json_encode`, it returns a result that you then have to use. Also, you aren't `print`ing an array correctly, use [`print_r`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)

Comment: is the array that I produced the same syntax wise of the json array that I wish? Im very lost in that part. I cant quite put a finger on it

Comment: here is my output of the array Array ( [adjacencies:] => Array ( [nodeTo] => 2 [nodeFrom] => 1 [data] => Array ( ) ) [data] => Array ( [$color] => #83548B [$type] => circle ) [id:] => 1 [name:] => Blue Jay )

Answer (score 0):

You want your array creation to look like:

```
$array = array(
  "adjacencies" => array(
      "nodeTo" => "$to",
      "nodeFrom" => "$id",
      "data" => array()
  ),
  "data" => array(
       '$color' => $color1,
       '$type' => $type1
  ),
  'id' => $id,
  'name' => $name
);
```

and that would give one result of `json_encode`, from there, depending on how you loop to get all the data back to your application. Though, you do need to assign `json_encode` to something like `$my_json = json_encode($array);`

Comment: Array ( [adjacencies:] => Array ( [nodeTo] => 2 [nodeFrom] => 1 [data] => Array ( ) ) [data] => Array ( [$color] => #83548B [$type] => circle ) [id:] => 1 [name:] => Blue Jay )                         here is what im getting using print_r however there isnt any commas anywhere

Comment: That's not a result from the code I put.  Also, there's no comma's because you have used `json_encode` on it, echo with `<pre>` tags to see it's format...

Comment: do the commas matter when encoding it to json?

Comment: No.  Have you never used PHP [arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) before?

Comment: yes I have, however I didnt encode it I just print_r and the output I got was this,I took encode out.  Array ( [adjacencies:] => Array ( [nodeTo] => 2 [nodeFrom] => 1 [data] => Array ( ) ) [data] => Array ( [$color] => #83548B [$type] => circle ) [id:] => 1 [name:] => Blue Jay )

Comment: Then once you encode it, you'll see the output closer to what you are wanting.

Comment: You're welcome!  If it helped, you should start accepting answers so people will be more willing to answer your questions in the future. ^^